# How to dict or data check keys in pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

```
class mail(BaseModel):
    mailid: int
    email: str
    
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    mails: List[mail]

data1 = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'mails':[
        {'mailid':1,'email':'aeajhs@gmail.com'}, 
        {'mailid':2,'email':'aeajhsds@gmail.com'}
    ]
}
userobj = User(**data1)  # Accepted
data2 = {
        'id': 123,
        'name': 'Jane Doe',
        'mails':[
            {'mailid':1,'email':'aeajhs@gmail.com'}, 
            {'email':'aeajhsds@gmail.com'}
        ]
    }
    
userobj = User(**data2)  # Discarded or not accepted
```

I want to check the keys in the dictionary that we passing to pydantic model so If the key is not present in the given dictionary I want to discard that data.
For example in data2 in mails `{'email':'aeajhsds@gmail.com'}` data2 must be discarded

Comment: use a validator?

Comment: Yes can you give me example code

Comment: Do you only want to discard that single item in the list, or do you want to refuse to generate the `User` object at all?

Comment: I want to discard total data

Comment: Can I use validator for user class with some keys only like id and name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `pydantic.validator` as @juanpa-arrivillaga said.

There are few little tricks:

- `Optional` it may be empty when the end of your validation.
- `pre=True` whether or not this validator should be called before the standard validators (else after)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from typing import List, Optional


class Mail(BaseModel):
    mailid: int
    email: str
    
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    mails: Optional[List[Mail]]

    @validator('mails', pre=True)
    def mail_check(cls, v):
        mail_att = [i for i in Mail.__fields__.keys()]
        mail_att_count = 0
        for i, x in enumerate(v):
            for k in dict(x).keys():
                if k in mail_att:
                    mail_att_count += 1
            if mail_att_count != len(mail_att):
                v.pop(i)
            mail_att_count = 0
        return v
```

```py
data = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'mails':[
        {'mailid':1,'email':'aaa@gmail.com'},
        {'mailid':2,'email':'bbb@gmail.com'},
        {'email':'ccc@gmail.com'}
    ]
}

x = User(**data)  # Discarded or not accepted
print(x.id)
print(x.name)
print(x.mails)

# Output
# >>123
# >>Jane Doe
# >>[Mail(mailid=1, email='aaa@gmail.com'), Mail(mailid=2, email='bbb@gmail.com')]
```

Comment: Can I use validator for user class with some keys only like id and name

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the `mails` list in a pre validation and do a simple `try`-clause to check if each `mail` item is correct:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ValidationError
from typing import List

class mail(BaseModel):
    mailid: int
    email: str

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    mails: List[mail]

    @validator("mails", pre=True)
    def must_be_valid_mail(cls, v):
        ret = []
        for item in list(v):
            try:
                mail(**item)
                ret.append(item)
            except ValidationError as er:
                print(er)
        return ret

data = {
    'id': 123,
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'mails':[
        {'mailid':1,'email':'aeajhs@gmail.com'}, 
        {'email':'aeajhsds@gmail.com'}
    ]
}

userobj = User(**data)
print(userobj)
```

Comment: Can I use validator for user class with some keys only like id and name

Comment: Yeah, you can write your own validators for any key you like: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you mean by "discarding" data.

Your current implementation should raise a `ValidationError` because `mailid` is missing in the second item in `mails` in `data2`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
mails -> 1 -> mailid
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If your intention is to simply *ignore* `data2` (or invalid input in general), I would suggest wrapping everything in a `try`-`except` block, e.g.:

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError

# your code here

try:
    userobj = User(**data2)
except ValidationError as exc:
    # Optional printout or logging:
    print(f"Encountered the following error when parsing `{data2}`:\n{exc}.\nSkipping...")
```

The program will now display the following message:

```
Encountered the following error when parsing `{'id': 123, 'name': 'Jane Doe', 'mails': [{'mailid': 1, 'email': 'aeajhs@gmail.com'}, {'email': 'aeajhsds@gmail.com'}]}`:
1 validation error for User
mails -> 1 -> mailid
  field required (type=value_error.missing).
Skipping...
```

### Alternative

If, on the other hand, you'd like to ignore the fact that `mailid` is missing, you could make it `Optional` in your model definition, for example:

```py
from typing import Optional

class mail(BaseModel):
    mailid: Optional[int]
    email: str

# ... everything stays the same

# This works now:
userobj = User(**data2)

print(userobj)
# id=123 name='Jane Doe' mails=[mail(mailid=1, email='aeajhs@gmail.com'), mail(mailid=None, email='aeajhsds@gmail.com')]
```

Comment: Can I use validator for user class with some keys only like id and name

Comment: You could always use `Optional` on any of the fields. See updated solution.